# range.Offset(0, 2).Select with runtime error 91 "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

Because I can't write `ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 3).Value + Korruption_mitte_number` with range, I referred to the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587154/how-do-i-add-1-to-all-cells-in-a-user-selected-range/77699483#77699483).
The copy & paste seem fine, because the target range (it's a cell actually) does increase. However, the line `ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2).Select` returns the runtime error 91 "object variable or With-block variable not set".

Below are partial codes:

```
Sub makro_versuch()

Dim ZSF As Worksheet
Set ZSF = Worksheets("Tabelle2")
Dim AVG As Worksheet
Set AVG = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
Dim VBK As Worksheet
Set VBK = Worksheets("Tabelle3")


'get the number of the last row with data in Zusammenfassung Warengruppe, AVG und VBK for the range of "for-loops"
lastRowZSF = ZSF.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowAVG = AVG.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowVBK = VBK.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row



'variables in AVG sheet
Dim wagr_range As Range
Dim findString As String
Dim wagr_first_row As Range
Dim fnd_cell As Range
Dim wagr_row_number As Integer 'used
Dim zsf_row_number As Integer 'used
Dim row_in_zsf As Variant
Dim column_in_zsf As Variant
Dim Korruption_gut_number As Integer 'used
Dim Korruption_mitte_number As Integer 'used
Dim Korruption_schlecht_number As Integer 'used
Dim Menschenrecht_gut_number As Integer 'used
Dim Menschenrecht_mitte_number As Integer 'used
Dim Menschenrecht_schlecht_number As Integer 'used
Dim Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number As Integer 'used
Dim Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number As Integer 'used
Dim Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number As Integer 'used
Dim Umweltschutz_gut_number As Integer 'used
Dim Umweltschutz_mitte_number As Integer 'used
Dim Umweltschutz_schlecht_number As Integer 'used


Dim check_criteria_vertical As Range
Dim check_criteria_horizontal As Range
Dim row_index_in_wagr As Integer 'used

'variables in ZSF sheet
Dim ZSF_rng As Range 'used


'initialize the criterion numbers
Korruption_gut_number = 0
Korruption_mitte_number = 0
Korruption_schlecht_number = 0
Menschenrecht_gut_number = 0
Menschenrecht_mitte_number = 0
Menschenrecht_schlecht_number = 0
Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number = 0
Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number = 0
Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number = 0
Umweltschutz_gut_number = 0
Umweltschutz_mitte_number = 0
Umweltschutz_schlecht_number = 0

'initialize the row numbers
wagr_row_number = 7 'used
zsf_row_number = 81 'used

Worksheets("Tabelle1").Activate
'for every value in column A from AVG
    'check the range of the merged cell in column A (wie viele Länder)
    Do While wagr_row_number <= lastRowAVG - 1
        RowCount = Range("A" & wagr_row_number).MergeArea.Rows.Count
        
        'set the check range in column G
        Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 6).Select
                        
        Worksheets("Tabelle2").Activate
        Do While zsf_row_number <= 96
                        
            Worksheets("Tabelle1").Activate
            'Check if the selected cell is "X" in the WAGR
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Korruption_schlecht_number = Korruption_schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Korruption_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Korruption_schlecht_number
            Korruption_schlecht_number = 0
                
            
            'set the check range in column H
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 7).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Korruption_mitte_number = Korruption_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Korruption_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = Korruption_mitte_number
            Korruption_mitte_number = 0
                
        
            'set the check range in column I
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 8).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Korruption_gut_number = Korruption_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Korruption_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 4).Value = Korruption_gut_number
            Korruption_gut_number = 0
        
            'set the check range in column J
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 9).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Menschenrecht_gut_number = Menschenrecht_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Menschenrecht_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 5).Value = Menschenrecht_gut_number
            Menschenrecht_gut_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column K
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 10).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Menschenrecht_mitte_number = Menschenrecht_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Menschenrecht_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 6).Value = Menschenrecht_mitte_number
            Menschenrecht_mitte_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column L
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 11).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Menschenrecht_schlecht_number = Menschenrecht_schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Menschenrecht_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 7).Value = Menschenrecht_schlecht_number
            Menschenrecht_schlecht_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column M
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 12).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number = Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 8).Value = Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number
            Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column N
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 13).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number = Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 9).Value = Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number
            Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column O
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 14).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    schlecht_number = schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 10).Value = Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number
            Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column P
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 15).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Umweltschutz_gut_number = Umweltschutz_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Umweltschutz_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 11).Value = Umweltschutz_gut_number
            Umweltschutz_gut_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column Q
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 16).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Umweltschutz_mitte_number = Umweltschutz_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Umweltschutz_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 12).Value = Umweltschutz_mitte_number
            Umweltschutz_mitte_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column R
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 17).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Umweltschutz_schlecht_number = Umweltschutz_schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Umweltschutz_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 13).Value = Umweltschutz_schlecht_number
            Umweltschutz_schlecht_number = 0
            
            'Jump to the next WAGR
            If row_index_in_wagr = RowCount + 1 Then
                Range("A" & wagr_row_number + 20).Offset(0, 6).Select
            End If
        
            zsf_row_number = zsf_row_number + 1
            wagr_row_number = wagr_row_number + 20
        Loop
        
    Loop
   
Dim rBlank As Range 'used
'initialize the row numbers again
wagr_row_number = 7 'used
zsf_row_number = 81 'used

Worksheets("Tabelle3").Activate
'for every value in column A from VBK
    'check the range of the merged cell in column A (wie viele Länder)
    Do While wagr_row_number <= lastRowVBK - 1
        RowCount = Range("A" & wagr_row_number).MergeArea.Rows.Count
        
        'set the check range in column G
        Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 6).Select
                        
        Worksheets("Tabelle2").Activate
        Do While zsf_row_number <= lastRowZSF - 1
        
     Worksheets("Tabelle3").Activate
            'Check if the selected cell is "X" in the WAGR
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Korruption_schlecht_number = Korruption_schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Korruption_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Worksheets("Tabelle2").Activate
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            MsgBox (wagr_row_number)
            Set rBlank = Cells(111, 16)
            'Put the current value in an unused cell and copy it
            rBlank.Value = Korruption_schlecht_number
            rBlank.Copy
           
            
            
            'Paste Special Add over the selection
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlAdd
                       

            'Get rid of the copied cell
            rBlank.ClearContents
            'Selection.Value = Selection.Value + Korruption_schlecht_number
            Korruption_schlecht_number = 0
                
            
            'set the check range in column H
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 7).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Korruption_mitte_number = Korruption_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Korruption_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 3).Value + Korruption_mitte_number
            Korruption_mitte_number = 0
                
        
            'set the check range in column I
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 8).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Korruption_gut_number = Korruption_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Korruption_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 4).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 4).Value + Korruption_gut_number
            Korruption_gut_number = 0
        
            'set the check range in column J
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 9).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Menschenrecht_gut_number = Menschenrecht_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Menschenrecht_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 5).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 5).Value + Menschenrecht_gut_number
            Menschenrecht_gut_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column K
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 10).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Menschenrecht_mitte_number = Menschenrecht_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Menschenrecht_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 6).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 6).Value + Menschenrecht_mitte_number
            Menschenrecht_mitte_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column L
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 11).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Menschenrecht_schlecht_number = Menschenrecht_schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Menschenrecht_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 7).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 7).Value + Menschenrecht_schlecht_number
            Menschenrecht_schlecht_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column M
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 12).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number = Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 8).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 8).Value + Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number
            Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column N
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 13).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number = Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 9).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 9).Value + Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number
            Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column O
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 14).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    schlecht_number = schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 10).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 10).Value + Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number
            Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column P
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 15).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Umweltschutz_gut_number = Umweltschutz_gut_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Umweltschutz_gut_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 11).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 11).Value + Umweltschutz_gut_number
            Umweltschutz_gut_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column Q
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 16).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Umweltschutz_mitte_number = Umweltschutz_mitte_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Umweltschutz_mitte_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 12).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 12).Value + Umweltschutz_mitte_number
            Umweltschutz_mitte_number = 0
            
            'set the check range in column R
            Range("A" & wagr_row_number).Offset(0, 17).Select
            For row_index_in_wagr = 1 To RowCount
                If Selection = "X" Then
                    Umweltschutz_schlecht_number = Umweltschutz_schlecht_number + 1
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ElseIf Selection <> "X" Then
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Next row_index_in_wagr
            'Return the Umweltschutz_schlecht_number in ZSF
            Set ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A" & wagr_row_number))
            ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 13).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 13).Value + Umweltschutz_schlecht_number
            Umweltschutz_schlecht_number = 0
            
            'Jump to the next WAGR
            If row_index_in_wagr = RowCount + 1 Then
                Range("A" & wagr_row_number + 20).Offset(0, 6).Select
            End If
        
            zsf_row_number = zsf_row_number + 1
            wagr_row_number = wagr_row_number + 20
        Loop
        
    Loop
        
        
        



End Sub
```

I did define and set `ZSF_rng`.

I set the `MsgBox(wagr_row_number)` and it returned 3 cells, which are the cells with the same values in two worksheets. I don't understand why there are 3 cells returned. In the first round `wagr_row_number = 7`, so `ZSF_rng` should be only one cell (there is no duplicate value in Tabelle3).

I also tried `ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd`, errors also pop up.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: There is no definition for `wagr_row_number`, `zsf_row_number`, `lastRowVBK`, `RowCount`, `lastRowZSF`, `row_index_in_wagr`, `Korruption_schlecht_number` in this code snippet, please provide more information

Comment: Are you sure `ZSF_rng = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("N81:N116").Find(...)` is actually returning a result?

Comment: `Set ZSF_rng = ..` if target value can't be found in the range, `ZSF_rng` is `Nothing`. "ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2).Select" returns the runtime error 91. If ZSF_rng is a cell, you can add value by `ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2)=ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2)+Cells(111, 16)` instead of PasteSpecial.

Comment: When using `Find`, always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters (you're missing the last two), and always test if the `Find` succeeded (linked thread).

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak, Yes, I've added them.

Comment: nicolaus-hee Yes, there are the target values in the two worksheets.
taller I tried your suggestion, but this time the same error pops in this line ><"
BigBen Thanks for your suggestion! There are actually more than 10 this methods above, and all of them work well. I'll provide the full codes.
Thanks for you guy in advance. I have to leave the office now.
Wish all of you a merry Christmas!